# How to use ColdFusion MySQL 5 spy log?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, coldfusion, datasource

I dumped the output of **getDatasources()** from **cfide.adminapi.datasource** component and I see two keys:

```
<cfscript>

isLoggedIn=createObject("component", "cfide.adminapi.administrator").login("x");
datasourceAPI=createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.datasource");

datasource = datasourceAPI.getDatasources(
        dsnname = 'mydsn'
    );

writedump(datasource);

</cfscript>
```

**spylogfile=""**
and
**usespylog=false**

Are they JDBC driver variable that coldfusion uses for MySQL5? How can I use them?

I can't find any documentation info for the usage. I tried usespylog=true and provided a full path for spylogfile="/tmp/test_spylog.log"

No file was created. Can anyone shed some light on this? seems interesting. Might be useful for debugging.

Comment: Those settings refer to the [sql spy feature added with the old DataDirect drivers](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2006/8/8/spy_jdbc_tool). However, I do not *think* the spy log is available for MySQL datasources, because they use different drivers. (I am not 100% positive though)

Comment: I think @Leigh is right. The spy logs contain the SQL used but also every JDBC API call made by CF to the driver. Its kind of useful, but its about 98% noise to 2% signal. I would look at setting up a JDBC logging proxy, such as this: https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/ (there are a number of others about)

Comment: The datasouce was created by setMysql5() function , NOT setMysql5_dd() which is for DataDirect.

Comment: Then that datasource probably does not support the sql spy features. AFAIK, it is only for dsn's that use the DataDirect drivers.

Comment: @barnyr - Do you know if that proxy be used with CF datasources? ie Does it have some sort of JDBC driver wrapper like [SeeFusion](http://www.seefusion.com/index.cfm?do=c_guide.configure).